# YII loads jquery-1.10.2.min.map

Tags: php, yii

```
CHtml::scriptFile('js/lightbox/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js');
```

I'am trying to load my own jquery, but then I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost/test/js/lightbox/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 404 (Not Found)
```

why it searches for .map extension, and not .js?

Answer (score 3):

In your jquery file there is some lines which is comment in top.like

```
/*! jQuery v1.10.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map
*/
```

just remove this line

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map
```

sourceMappingURL is an HTML5 feature.